# To show a function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Let $G\subset\mathbb C$ be open and connected, and function $h$ is analytic on $G$. $\{f_n(z)\}$ is a sequence of analytic functions on $G$ for which $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(z)$ exists for any $z$ in $G$. Define $f(z)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{f_n(z)}$. Suppose that $|f'_n(z)|\leq|h(z)|$ for any $z\in G$. Prove that $f\in H(G)$.

$ $

$ $

My idea: first to show $f(z)$ is continuous then use Morera's Theorem to show $f$ is analytic. But I have no idea of $h$. How to use $|f'_n(z)|\leq|h(z)|$ for any $z\in G$? What does it imply?

Comment: The answer to your question is in your first step. How are you showing $f$ is continuous? The given limit is not said to be uniform. Can you use the condition on $h$ to show some subsequence of $f_n $ does converge uniformly on compacts? If yes, then this subsequence is suitable to apply your proof plan.

Comment: Thanks @Ocambole. Still stuck. Can you help figure it out?

Comment: What do we know about $h$? If, for example, $h=f'$ then we can't conclude anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use Morera's theorem for $f_n$. The details are below.

> For any compact $K$ of $G$ the inequality $|f'_n(z)|<|h(z)|$ shows that $f'_n$ are uniformly bounded on $K$. Therefore the family $\{f'_n\}$ is normal (Montel's theorem). Therefore there is a subsequence $f'_{n_k}$ that converges uniformly. Hence $f_{n_k}$ converges uniformly (to $f$). Now your plan is applicable. $f$ is continuous for being the uniform limit of continuous function (analytic actually). And Morera is satisfied for $f$ because it is satisfied for $f_{n_k}$ and they converge uniformly to $f$.

Comment: Very clear. Thank you!